# How to format a number such that first 6 digits and last 4 digits are not hidden

Tags: c#, regex

How to format a number such that first 6 digits and last 4 digits are not hidden

such that 111111111111111 looks like 111111****1111

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace those four numbers with asterisks in a string?

Comment: @Farai You now have not one but three separate working solutions to choose from : mine which is the simplest to understand but requires 2 more lines and more allocated memory. The  you have Avinash Raj Answer which uses Regex for a elegant one liner and as you tagged Regex this could very well be the right way for you or  w.b which built a very efficient LINQ which will prob. preform the fastest out of the 3  answers.... you should pick one though ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use LINQ, substituting chars with indexes more than 5 and less than `number.Length - 4` with `*`:

```
string number = "111111111111111";

string res = new string(number.Select((c, index) => { return (index <= 5 || index >= number.Length - 4) ? c : '*'; }).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(res); // 111111*****1111
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is to slit the input..

```
int number = 111111111111111;

string firstsix  =  number.ToString().Substring(0,6) //gets the first 6 digits
string middlefour = number.ToString().Substring(6,4) //gets the next 4
string rest = number.ToString().Substring(10, number.ToString().Lenght) //gets the rest

string combined = firstsix  + "****" +rest;
```

Comment: alternatively you could use  `string lastfour= number.ToString().Substring(number.ToString().Substring(number.ToString().Lenghts-4, 4)` If the number lenght is not fixed...

Comment: Just remember that `int` has up to 10 digits (of which the first one is 0, 1, 2)

Comment: @xanatos you are absolutely correct, Single or double should do the trick, or depending on how the number is received just make it a String to start out with

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\G` anchor in-order to do a continuous string match.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?:^(.{6})|\G).(?=.{4})", "$1*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE1fJ0/6)

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/1sD2t2)